# Is there a common name for $O(x^{cx})$ type functions?

Tags: asymptotics

Is there a common name for the growth rate of functions that are asymptotically on the order of $x^{cx}$, for some $c$? The term *super-exponential* is much too general. The factorial function grows in this way -- so would it be appropriate to say that similar real-valued functions have "factorial growth"?

Comment: Note that $x^{cx} \in \Theta(x!)$ only for a particular choice of $c$ ($c=1$).  It grows much faster (slower) than $x!$ for $c>1$ ($c<1$).

Comment: That's right. In a similar way, $e^x$ grows much faster than $2^x$, but they're both called exponential functions.

I'm looking for a catch-all term that describes all functions that grow as fast as $x^{cx}$, for some value of $c$.